# In App Purchasing In Android: Purchase signature failed

Tags: android

I purchased an item using test account. I purchased an item as `android.test.purchase` but when refresh an activity i am getting following error:-

> Error:Failed to query inventory: IabResult : Error refreshing
>   inventory (querying owned items).(response : 1003 : Purchase signature
>   verification failed)

If anyone have idea about this issue. Please reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After struggle,finally i found a solution.

Means google play does not return signature for android.test.purchased item.

So, don't worry for the above issue it will work for real product only.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here
I've found a ticket open for this bug on the url below.

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=150

It has not yet been confirmed but i sent a message to some devs involved on that code to check this.